# recovering textedit crash

Tags: data-recovery, textedit

My laptop was low on ram and I just had a message saying that TextEdit crashed. TextEdit had multiple windows opened and I see that they are all gone, replaced with a single blank untitled RTF document window.

Other than the "recently opened" list which isn't helping at all, Is there some way to search for the lost content? For example a backup file or a dump file somewhere on the system?

Comment: Were they saved in some way at all?  If so, do you have Time Machine running?

Comment: @Allan, Time Machine not enabled. The files aren't saved, but I believe text edit has them saved to a temporary file.